# Using Cypher, how to return a node with only a subset of its properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Say I've created a node in Neo4j:

```
CREATE (:Thing {a:'foo', b:'bar'})
```

I can write a query to get that node with all of its properties

```
MATCH (n:Thing {a:'foo'}) RETURN n
```

which returns

```
{
  "a": "foo",
  "b": "bar"
}
```

but is it possible to match a node and retrieve only a subset of its properties, so that for example, Neo4j would return a **node** with only

```
{
  "b": "bar"
}
```

(Not looking for just the property, like you would get via `RETURN n.b`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use map projections in Cypher, for eg :

```
MATCH (n:Thing {a:'foo'}) RETURN n{.a}
```

will return :

```
 {a:"foo"}
```

More info in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (that I also have) because this also doesn't seem to return node objects or a subgraph.  For example, `MATCH (n)<-[r:REL]-(m) RETURN r, m{.prop1}` should return a subgraph of all nodes with that relationship, but the nodes would only have the `prop1` property.  This returns only the single property for each node, but doesn't retain the graph structure.