# How to specify label-based list of properties for returned nodes in a path

Tags: filter, neo4j, properties, cypher, return-value

I have a cypher query returning a quite large graph, with different node labels and relationships types. I want to optimize it a bit network-load-wise by only retrieving useful properties of my nodes and relationships.

How can I filter the map of nodes & relationships properties without altering the graph path ? i.e keep every element (nodes and relationships) but, for each returned node or relationship, get only a subset of its properties depending on labels.

e.g.:
for each :Person return only firstName, lastName, and dateOfBirth
for each :Business only an id and postCode
for each relationships of type :WORK_AT return jobTitle and startDate.

Note : Some nodes are multi-labels in this example it could be one-person-businesses that have both labels :Person:Business and those should have both set of properties for persons and companies returned.

Comment: For reference found this related question but it doesn't answer mine (no graph structure returned) :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717348/using-cypher-how-to-return-a-node-with-only-a-subset-of-its-properties

Answer (score 1):

You can use APOC functions to return [virtual nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.virtual.fromNode/) or [relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/5/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.vRelationship/) with a subset of their properties.

An example based on the movies graph

```
MATCH path = (n:Person)-[r]->(:Movie)<-[r2]-(o:Person)
UNWIND relationships(path) AS rel
WITH apoc.create.vRelationship(
    apoc.create.virtual.fromNode(
        startNode(rel),
        CASE 
            WHEN 'Person' IN labels(startNode(rel)) THEN ['name']
            WHEN 'Movie' IN labels(startNode(rel)) THEN ['title']
        END
    ),
    type(rel),
    // assuming for rels we return all properties
    rel{.*},
    apoc.create.virtual.fromNode(
        endNode(rel),
        CASE 
            WHEN 'Person' IN labels(endNode(rel)) THEN ['name']
            WHEN 'Movie' IN labels(endNode(rel)) THEN ['title']
        END
    )
) AS vrel
RETURN startNode(vrel), endNode(vrel), vrel
```

Would return Person nodes with only name and Movie nodes with only title

[image]

You need to know certain limitations to this :

- `apoc.create.virtual.fromNode` will produce Node objects but the `id` of the node will be `-id(originalNode) - 1` ( ref [here](https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/blob/9b8e78a2b868cf63ae89e48b25efc72898acfa20/common/src/main/java/apoc/result/VirtualNode.java#L52) )
- `ids` of the virtual relationships will be random negative numbers, if knowing the id is important, you can add it in the properties of the relationship as a computed value, for eg :

```
// assuming for rels we return all properties + ID of the relationship
    rel{.*, __id: id(rel)},
```

producing then

[image]

- Be careful as using virtual nodes/relationships in the beginning can lead to mistakes returning multiple times the same relationship

Comment: I tried your proposition :

I initially got a lot of duplicated relationships and figured I needed a "WITH DISTINCT" after the UNWIND.

I still get all the properties in the end... I will try researching further in the documentation thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: I don't really understand, I tried vRelationShip and virtual.fromNode individually with no issue but combining them returns the original nodes unaltered.

Comment: @VincentChalmel Can you maybe edit your question with what you tried ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @ChristopheWillemsen, I had vacations and others matters do deal with, I will have to ask a different question I think, I found that the reason I can't make this work is that neo4j seems to include in the path some related nodes and relationships i didn't asked for.